# Android - Change back button icon color on Material 3 theme

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-jetpack-navigation, material3

I have a single activity app and the activity's theme extends the `Theme.Material3.DayNight` theme.

My Activity has no custom toolbar and it has a Bottom Navigation. I'm using the Jetpack Navigation library to navigate between fragments.

When I navigate to another fragment (not via Bottom Navigation), an arrow appears on the toolbar, and if I click it, it send's me back to the previous fragment, which is what I expected to happen.

However, I'd like to change the arrow icon color, but I'm not figuring out how.

I have tried to get the `supportActionBar` from my activity and find the view, but I had no success.

I also tried the layout inspector, but it only displayes the views that are bellow the toolbar.

Like I mentioned, my Main Acitivity style is like this:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
        ...
    </style>
```

The layout of my Main Acitity is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Honk.Custom.Indicator"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm setting up the views on my Main Acitivity like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupMainScreen()
    }

    private fun setupMainScreen() {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view)
        val navController = (fragment as NavHostFragment).navController
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.navigation_clients, R.id.navigation_vehicles, R.id.navigation_settings)
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        findViewById<Toolbar>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.action_bar)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view)
        val navController = (fragment as NavHostFragment).navController
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`setupActionBarWithNavController` internally uses [`DrawerArrowDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable) to draw the Up icon.

As seen in [`DrawerArrowDrawable`'s source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.java;l=134), the color is pulled from your theme:

```
final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(null,
    R.styleable.DrawerArrowToggle, R.attr.drawerArrowStyle,
    R.style.Base_Widget_AppCompat_DrawerArrowToggle);
```

And looking at what [AppCompat's default styling is](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:appcompat/appcompat/src/main/res/values/styles.xml;l=86), this theme attribute is already set for you:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle"
       parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>
</style>
```

So where this color is coming from is already from the theme of your app - the `colorControlNormal`. By changing that, you'd change the color of your Up icon as well (note: this would also change a lot of things in your app, which is why the default is almost always already the correct choice).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that did not work on my project. However, it changed the color for some vector assets I have set on some ImageViews. I put this on my app theme: <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>